# requestAnimationFrame - browser support issues

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

http://jsfiddle.net/xwF6E/14/

Above is a JSfiddle of an animation i'm trying to create. It's works 100% fine in Chrome, however having various issues in other browsers.

It appears that in firefox it doesn't render the animation. As per the the Mozilla Dev Network docs @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame , i believe i've added cross browser support but perhaps i'm doing something wrong.

In IE (8 + 10, at least) it does not render the animation, nor my radial gradient (also a side issue if anyone can help).

IE gives me a IndexSizeError error on this line of code

```
var imageData = context.createImageData(context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
```

But i'm not sure what that means specifically, and I can't find much regarding that error/that method.

Anyone able to enlighten me please?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you figured this out by now, but for anyone else that might be interested, the cause is this code that's trying to get the window size:

```
context.canvas.width = document.width;
context.canvas.height = document.height;
```

You'll want to do something more like this:

```
context.canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
context.canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
```

Though it can actually be a little more complicated than that. See this for more information on finding window height and width:
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

Here's the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shaunwest/MALN2/

Comment: Thankyou very much for this! Was actually surprised to get an answer to this one.
My fault for not updating, the application of it I used actually didn't require the window dimensions, so I avoided the problem entirely.
Cheers